# Order by an invisible aggregate column / Excluding columns from a result

Tags: sql, plsql, sas

I need to return a table that contains the top 10 most commonly used ids, where the id is used more than 1 times.

Example data:

2
2
2
1
1
1
1
3
3
4
4
5
6

Top 10:

1 2 3 4 (no more due to the example data)

This is my query:

```
proc sql outobs=10;
SELECT id, count(id) as COLX
FROM output
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) GT 1
ORDER BY COLX DESC;
```

This works perfectly. It returns the 10 ids that appear the most in output. **However**, I do not want to include `count(id)` in my output. Sadly, I cannot seem to find a way to exclude this column without throwing an error.

**I have tried:**

A: Moving the aggregate directly into ORDER BY (this exact code works in vanilla pl/sql, but not in SAS).

```
proc sql outobs=10;
SELECT id
-- SELECT id, count(id) as COLX
FROM output
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) GT 1
ORDER BY count(id) DESC;
-- ORDER BY COLX DESC;
```

> ERROR: Summary functions are restricted to the SELECT and HAVING clauses only.

B: Moving the query into a subquery, and selecting the columns I need.

```
proc sql outobs=10;
SELECT id FROM (
SELECT id, count(id) as COLX
FROM output
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) GT 1
ORDER BY COLX DESC
);
```

> *(points at ORDER BY)* Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, ), *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, EQT, EXCEPT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, INTERSECT, LE, LET, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, OR, OUTER, UNION, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.

Removing `ORDER BY` fixes this, but it makes my top 10 list useless since it's not actually sorted anymore.

Does anyone know why this is causing me so much grief? It really is a very simple query that has been complicated by this one requirement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you required to use SQL or can you use PROC FREQ?

Comment: @Reeza I am just much more familiar with SQL, so I jumped at the opportunity to use it as I am very new to SAS. My data is just a simple sas dataset created from a CSV file. Do you think I could generate the required data with PROC FREQ?

Comment: How about put the query into a subquery and do select on the subquery to pick the id column only?

Comment: @kc2018 Is that not what I am doing in example B?

Comment: Are you trying to create a data set with this values? Or do you want the printed output?

Comment: Did you try giving the subquery an alias?

Comment: @Reeza I am just looking to print the output. This is just for a QA report to be sent in an email. The results are thrown away immediately.

Comment: @kc2018 What do you mean, exactly? I don't understand how that would help, since I don't reference it anywhere. Wouldn't that just be placing a name after my subquery?

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer below to show how you can do this with a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way IMO would be to use a SAS data step option KEEP, this works when you're creating a data set. If you don't want a data set then you'll need another option.

```
data have;
input id @@;
cards;
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 3 4 4 5 6
;;;;
run;

proc sql outobs=10;
create table want (keep=id) as
SELECT id, count(id) as COLX
FROM have
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) GT 1
ORDER BY COLX DESC;
quit;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Assuming you want no table, based on your comments, you can use the nested query and put the ORDER after the subquery. You can order by variables you don't select, but not summary functions.

```
proc sql outobs=10;
select id from (
SELECT id, count(id) as COLX
FROM have
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(id) GT 1) 
order by colx desc;
quit;
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your help and quick responses. The second solution worked perfectly for my use-case. :)